# PHP/Session/Caching - Unable to remove logged in user from index.php page after processing logout.php?

Tags: php, session

I have a three PHP scripts (logout.php, index.php, session.php) that I use in a larger application.  I incorporated session.php (to serve as a mechanism to control preserving page view for pressing back button on the browser).

I am trying to make the logout.php clear cache and the logged in user info on the webpage but no matter what I do I can not seem to logout. That is, the user still remains on my page as logged in.

How can I logout to ensure that the user does not appear as logged in on my index.php page?

**session.php**

```
<? 
  session_cache_limiter('public');
  session_start();
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"EXPIRES\" CONTENT=\"Mon, 02 May 2015 21:00:00 GMT\">";
    header('Location: index.php');                                             
?>
```

**beginning of index.php script**

```
<?php   
    session_start(); 
    if (isset($_SESSION['expire']))
    {              
        echo $_SESSION['expire'];
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION);
    } 
?>
```

Error Log shows the following each time I try to logout.

PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in index.php on line 6   <-- this is referring to where I have session_start() in my if block in my local code.

**EDIT - Modified index.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['expire']))
    {      
        session_start();        
        echo $_SESSION['expire'];
        session_destroy();
    } 
    else
    {
        require_once('session.php');
    }
?>
```

**Latest index.php script**

```
<?php
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    {
        require_once('session.php');
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();  
        if (isset($_SESSION['expire']))
        { 
            $expire = $_SESSION['expire'];
            session_destroy();
            echo $expire;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Note you are using short tags `<?` instead of `<?php` in session.php. That could have consequences.  Do you have display_errors enabled? Problems with setting the session cookie or `header()` calls would become obvious. In your topmost include `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always when developing & testing code.  Ensure all your scripts are able to report errors, especially logout.php.

Comment: When I add back the regular tag and when I die() before I redirect to index.php my browser is still redirecting to index.php.   What I am puzzled about is why after I add die(); that the script still redirects to index.php.   I tried ini_set and error_reporting but I did not see any errors.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the issue here is most likely that echo before destroying the session. I might add, `session_destroy` is enough, you don't need to call `session_unset` at all and please do NOT do `unset($_SESSION)`, just don't.

Comment: @ggg, I am trying to echo the meta tag to try to remove any cached info.  Do you suggest not echoing before session_destroy()?

Comment: At what point do you have `session_start()` inside the `if ()` block? That's not above, and unless you have additional calls to `session_start()` in index.php you would not see that error.

Comment: I didn't notice that echo in the unset block - that potentially cause the "headers already sent" error when attempting to modify the session cookie state.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I edited the code to have session_start() correctly placed in my if block.  I had it incorrect initially.      There are no errors in php error log, only that the user still remains when I go to logout.php.

Comment: right, so the "session already started" error is usually caused by multiple `session_start` calls - there still is an issue with that echo that should go after `session_destroy`: just store `$_SESSION['expire']` inside a variable and echo that variable after you finished working with the session.

Comment: When I comment out session_cache_limiter('public'); and try to reload the page after I add a test message echoed from my if block, I get only the old message?  Is this a caching issue and if so why can't I see new content echoed even though there is caching happening?

Comment: Ok, so after inserting in an html5 doctype and a one time refresh meta tag output ( to counter the need to press logout twice) I succeeded in logging out.  I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formulated the code below for my scripts which resolved the logout issue I was encountering.  I narrowed down the cause of my issue to probably incorrectly interpreted/parsed html code im my browser which I noticed as red tags in my page source code.

After adding in the doctype and the metatags after the doctype in the php script before `<html>` tag I got my page to logout successfully!

**index.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        session_start();
        if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        {
            require_once('session.php');
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['expire']))
        { 
            $expire = $_SESSION['expire'];
            session_destroy();
            echo $expire;
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
        } 
    ?>
    <html>
    ... rest of code not shown
```

**session.php**

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  session_cache_limiter('public');
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"EXPIRES\" CONTENT=\"Mon, 02 May 2015 21:00:00 GMT\">";
    header('Location: index.php');                                             
?>
```

Comment: Still unsure as to why I need to press logout twice but I temporarily got a solution that is close to what I needed.  I will investigate the issue further to see why I still need to press logout twice.

Comment: You _cannot_ place the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration before the PHP code. The call to `session_start()` will fail there because you have already sent output.  Did you already have that indented whitespace before the opening `<?php`? If so, that likewise would prevent `session_start()` from being called. Those are all causes of the [infamous Headers already sent error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php). Though it may seem like it works with this refactor, you should go over every scenario carefully. It seems like it would cause problems.

Comment: For example, it may not be that the logout has actually completed successfully, but rather that you just don't see the active session reloaded on that script because the `session_start()` call has failed because of the doctype placement.

Comment: I did move down the doctype to below php code  following the suggestion and when I try to access a page that is restricted to logged in users I can not access the page I am forced to log back in again with appropriate credentials.   I am hopeful that this resolves the issue.  But I am still uncertain as to why I have to do a double click on logout.